# How do I implement a custom server_error which renders response content in correct format?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a custom server_error function to return json response for 500 error using DRF:

```
def api_server_error(request, template_name=None):

    return HttpResponseServerError(json.dumps({'detail': 'Internal server error'}),
                                   content_type="application/json", status=500)
```

But what I really want to do is render the response in the requested format, e.g., xml, json, etc. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

By returning drf Response:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

return Response({'detail' : "Internal server error"}, status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me started in the right direction. See full solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to @djangozone who got me started in the right direction, I came up with a solution. My question began because I presumed that because server_error is called outside DRF, that it would limit my ability to use DRF features to deliver a properly formatted response. There was some more work to do in order to get DRF to render it properly. Here it is:

```
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework import status
import re

def get_format_suffix(request):

    suffix_pattern = r'\.([a-z0-9]+)$'
    match = re.search(suffix_pattern, request.path)
    format = match and match.group(1)

    return format

def api_server_error(request, template_name=None):

    drf_request = Request(request)
    format_suffix = get_format_suffix(drf_request)
    accepted_renderer = drf_request.negotiator.select_renderer(
        drf_request, [renderer() for renderer in api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES], format_suffix=format_suffix
    )

    response = Response({'detail' : "Internal server error"}, status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    response.accepted_renderer = accepted_renderer[0]
    response.accepted_media_type = response.accepted_renderer.media_type
    response.renderer_context = {'request': drf_request}
    response.render()

    return response
```

Comment: Lol, I thought that it would work that way by default. If you take a look in the rest_framework source code, in the file mixings.py, all method always return a Response without doing all this stuff you are doing (and it works when you ask for a specific render method with .xml, .json, etc. Ofc, you need to specify the renderer classes in your settings or view). Don't know if there is a better way to achieve that or where rest_framework is doing this.

Comment: The problem is the extra code I wrote is what the view actually does behind the scenes, and server_error operates outside a view. Since we're not working with a view here to do the work, I had to copy the relevant parts.

Comment: ah, ok. I'll explore it also when I have time. Glad it does work now ^^.